# Multi caret insert/edit of selection in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, multiline, textselection

I want to refactor some code which consists of repeating values using vs code.
I am aware of

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+d",
  "command": "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
  "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

which inserts more cursors one by one after each press to the places of matching selection.

In Visual Studio there is shortcut:

`Insert carets at all matching  Shift+Alt+;     Edit.InsertCaretsatAllMatching`

And I'm unable to find equivalent in vs code.

Comment: `Select All Occurrences of Find Match` `Ctrl+Shift+L`

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand these completely different descriptions  of functions of almost the same product. Is there any comprehensible mix of shortcuts from visual studio and visual studio code?